# How to export from Network F12 Developer Tools window in Safari?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, developer-tools

I have successfully finished running a network profiling session using Safari.

1. Run Safari and open F12 tools.
2. Go to the `Network` tab.
3. Load a page.
4. Get results in table.

Now I want to save this table. Export it somewhere in whatever format. How to do? Thanks.